# The budget of Exact Online for budget scenario 002 is being shown as 0 instead of the actual value

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

In Microsoft Excel I've a formula to retrieve the budget from Exact Online for budget scenario code 002 as follows:

```
I_EOL_BGT_PDER_LINE_AMOUNT(;$B$2;eol_boekjaar;1;12;A7)
```

B2 contains "002", eol_boekjaar is a named range which is the current fiscal year 2016, and A7 contains 700100 which is the account number. 1 and 12 are the starting and end fiscal period in 2016 for which the budget is to be summed together.

Outcome of the formula is 0 instead of the actual total budget for this general ledger account.

Question: why is the actual total bduget for this general ledger account in Exact Online not appearing?

Answer (score 0):

Please check your formula. The `I_EOL_BGT_PDER_LINE_AMOUNT` requires as second argument the budget scenario which in general does not contain double quotes. It is often solely 1, or for instance the year for which the budget is. In your case I think the double quotes are superfluous.

Please note that Excel for cells with general style automatically transforms anything with leading zeroes into a number, effectively removing the leading zeroes.

The way to solve this is to use either a text format on the cell or formula like `="00000digits"`.

Did this solve it for you?